# Storing individual frames in an array from a video in Python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, video-processing

I'm using Opencv modules to open and display my video. What I would like to do is store the individual frames in an array and work on them in a dependent manner. 
I tried using:

```
for i< framecount

ret,frame[i]=cap.read()
```

where cap has the video and framecount has the number of frames in the video, but it is not working! Any ideas?

ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (288,360,3) into shape (360,3)

Comment: Could you paste the error message?

Answer (score 0):

If you declare the array as follows

```
import numpy as np

w = frame.shape[0]
h = frame.shape[1]
d = frame.shape[2]
framearray = np.empty((framecount, w, h, d), dtype=frame.dtype)
```

You can unpack as needed

```
for i in range(framecount):
    _, framearray[i] = cap.read()
```